# Integrate logarithmic derivative of a periodic function

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals

Given $f$ a $p$-periodic function over $\mathbb{C}$, how to show that :
$$\frac{1}{\mathrm{i}p}\int_a^{a+p}\frac{f'(t)}{f(t)}dt \in \mathbb{Z}$$

Is there any elegant method ?

Comment: In fact, we find $\frac{2\pi}{p}$. Or you sure that $p$ is not something like $p=k\pi$ ?

Comment: @surb : thanks, actually, the question is given with $p=2\pi$ initially and I assumed a wrong generalisation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\gamma: [0, 1] \to \Bbb C$ be a path connecting $a$ and $a+p$.
Then 
$$
 \int_a^{a+p}\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)} \, dz = \int_0^1 \frac{f'(\gamma(t))\gamma'(t)}{f(\gamma(t))} \, dt
= \int_\Gamma \frac{dw}{w} = 2 \pi i \operatorname{N}(\Gamma, 0)
$$
where $\Gamma = f \circ \gamma$ is a *closed* path, and $\operatorname{N}(\Gamma, 0)$ is the [*winding number*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winding_number) of $\Gamma$ with respect to zero.
The winding number is an integer (see below), and therefore
$$
 \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_a^{a+p}\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)} \in \Bbb Z \, .
$$

Why is the winding number an integer? I am pretty sure that
this has been shown before, but I could not find it anymore, therefore
I try to reproduce an elementary proof here.

For $0 \le s \le 1$, define
$$
 F(s) :=  \int_0^s \frac{\Gamma'(t)}{\Gamma(t)} \, dt \, .
$$
Then verify that the derivative of 
$$
  e^{-F(s)}\Gamma(s)
$$
with respect to $s$ is zero. It follows that
$$
 \Gamma(s) = C e^{F(s)} 
$$
for some constant $C$. From $\Gamma(0) = \Gamma(1)$ it follows that
$$
 e^{F(0)} = e^{F(1)}
$$
and therefore
$$
  F(1) = F(0) + 2 \pi i k = 2 \pi i k
$$
for some $k \in \Bbb Z$, which is what we wanted to show.

---

*Re your comments:* Here is a direct proof for your special case
$a, a+p \in \Bbb R$, using the same ideas, but without integration 
along paths in $\Bbb C$:

For $x \in \Bbb R$, define 
$$
 F(x) = \int_0^x \frac{f'(t)}{f(t)} \, dt
$$
Then verify that the derivative of
$$
  e^{-F(x)} f(x)
$$
with respect to $x$ is zero. It follows that
$$
  f(x) = C e^{F(x)}
$$
for some constant $C$. From $f(a) = f(a+p)$ it follows that
$$
 e^{F(a)} = e^{F(a+p)}
$$
and therefore 
$$
  F(a+p) = F(a) + 2 \pi i k 
$$
for some $k \in \Bbb Z$. So we have 
$$
\int_a^{a+p} \frac{f'(t)}{f(t)} \, dt = F(a+p) - F(a) = 2 \pi i k \, .
$$

Comment: $f$ is a function with a real variable.

Comment: @servabat: I am confused now. Your question says: "Given $f$ a $p$-periodic function over $\mathbb{C}$." So where is $f$ defined, and what does it map to?

Comment: It has a complex value but a real variable. Else, I don't know how is defined the integral yet.

Comment: @servabat: Well, I have just chosen $z$ as the integration variable because I *assumed* that you consider $f$ in the plane. But everything above  remains correct if you restrict $z$ to be real.

Comment: But then $\gamma$ is just an affine function ? The problem for me is the 3rd equality, I don't understand that part. It seems pretty close to Surb answer, and I think it uses topics I haven't studied yet.

Comment: @servabat: See update. Does that help?

Comment: Indeed, it is intersting, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

By periodicity, $$\int_a^{a+p}\frac{f'(t)}{f(t)}\mathrm d t\underset{z=f(t)}{=}\int_{f(a)}^{f(a+p)}\frac{1}{z}\mathrm d z\underset{periodicity}{=}\int_{\gamma }\frac{1}{z}\mathrm d z$$
where $\gamma $ is a closed curve. Using cauchy formula, you can prove the claim.

Comment: Well I don't know the Cauchy formula, is there any alternative ?

Comment: Not really... But you don't know at least that $$\int_\gamma \frac{1}{z}\mathrm d z=\begin{cases}2\pi i& 0\in \text{Int}(\gamma )\\ 0&0\notin \text{Closure}(\text{Int}(\gamma ))\end{cases},$$ where $\gamma $ is a closed (simple) curve ?

Comment: No, I never studied geometry with analysis (closed curves, etc..)

Comment: To my opinion, it's unsolvable without this... let's see if somebody else answer...

Comment: nothing complicated here. by definition of a contour integral, if $\gamma(t),t \in [A,B]$ is a parametrized curve in the complex plane : $\int_\gamma h(z) dz = \int_A^B h(\gamma(t)) \gamma'(t) dt$ so $\int_a^{a+p} \frac{f'(t)}{f(t)} dt = \int_A^B \frac{1}{\gamma(t)} \gamma'(t) dt = \int_\gamma \frac{1}{z} dz$ where $\gamma(t) = f(t), A = a, B = a+p$. $\quad$ what is complicated is that in $\int_\gamma h(z) dz$ we can stretch the contour $\gamma$ as we want, if $h(z)$ is holomorphic (analytic), but in the case of $h(z) = \frac{1}{z}$ it should be possible to show it by elementary means

Comment: @user1952009: The problem is not here ! How do you integrate $\int_\gamma \frac{1}{z}\mathrm d z$ without Cauchy formula ? The final answer is just a factor of this integral. What you say in your previous post doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: and the expected elementary answer to this exercice is that $\int_x^y \frac{f'(t)}{f(t)} dt \simeq \log(f(y))- \log(f(x))$ where all the problem is to choose the correct branch of $\log$. Hence we construct a function $F(t)$ such that $F'(t) = \frac{f'(t)}{f(t)}$ for every $t \in (a,a+p)$, and we see that $F(t) = \log(f(t)) - \log(f(a)) + 2i \pi k$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ depending on $t$

Comment: @user1952009: you can imagine that if the OP doesn't now cauchy formula, what you wrote will be not understandable for him ! ;-)

Comment: if $G(t) = \ln |f(t)|$ then $G'(t) = Re(f'(t)/f(t))$ and $G(b) - G(a) = \int_a^b Re(f'(t)/f(t)) dt$, so all the problem is to prove that $Im(\int_a^{a+p} f'(t)/f(t) dt) = 2 i \pi k$